# Regex not accepting specific characters

Tags: regex

I have the following password Regex `^((?=[\S]{8})(?:.*)(?=[A-Z]{1})(?:.*)(?=[\p{S}])(?:.*))$` which captures the following criterion

```
At least 8 chars long
At least 1 Capital Letter
At least 1 Special Character
```

However it doesnt accept the following characters : `!@#%&*()_-\/,?` How can I adjust the regex to incorporate these characters. Here is a sample of the code:https://regex101.com/r/hE2dD2/1
 Thanks again

Comment: does that input satisfy criterion 3?

Comment: I'd recommend against trying to validate passwords in one regex, by the way. It's more error-prone than validating each rule separately, which also makes it much easier to change your rules and tell what's going on in the code.

Comment: @Saif yes unless your seeing an error Id be glad to accept another recommendation

Comment: sorry i meant condition 2 ?  At least 1 Capital Letter

Comment: @Saif have a look at the code: https://regex101.com/r/hE2dD2/1

Comment: Injecting looahead assertions mid-stream after consumption sets a left to right order of the criterion. Factor out the most specific ones and look for them at the beginning anchor ^. That's mostly where the assertions go on simple validation.

Answer (score 1):

Add those characters into the place where it checks the special characters, with appropriate escaping:

```
((?=[\S]{8})(?:.*)(?=[A-Z]{1})(?:.*)(?=[\p{S}!@#%&*()_\-\\\/,?])(?:.*))$
```

But if you don't understand the regex enough to do that change, how is anyone else maintaining your code supposed to follow it? Make it separate, simple tests as @Michelle commented, e.g. Python pseudocode:

```
if len(password) < 8: 
    print "password too short"

elif not re.match('[A-Z]', password):
    print "Password must contain a capital letter"

elif ...
```

That way, you can find out why it failed and present a more useful message, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `\p{S}`, just use this regex:

```
^(?=.*?\p{Lu})(?=.*?[^\p{L}\p{N}\n])\S{8,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE2dD2/2)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

^((?=[\S]{8})(?:.*)(?=[A-Z]{1})(?:.*)(?=[\p{S}]|[^[A-Za-z0-9]+])(?:.*))$

Comment: Do you want to require one of them or include them in 'At least 1 special character'?